# R - Merging columns and renaming values

Tags: r

To perform an ANOVA I am looking to merge this data in a new variable called `CompensationGroup`. Thereby, people who have been in "Compensationproject1" should be displayed as `1`, people who have been in "Compensationproject2" should be displayed as `2`...

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(Compensationproject2 = case_when(
Compensationproject2 == 1 ~ 2,
T ~ NA_real_
  )) %>%
  mutate(Compensationproject3 = case_when(
Compensationproject3 == 1 ~ 3,
T ~ NA_real_
  )) %>% 
      unite("CompensationGroup",c(Compensationproject1,Compensationproject2,Compensationproject3),remove = F,na.rm = T) %>% 
 mutate(CompensationGroup = str_extract(CompensationGroup,'\\d'))""
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that does not require the use of `pivot`. However, it requires the use of a bunch of other `tidyverse`functions ala `mutate`, `case_when`, `unite` and `str_extract`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~id,~Comp1,~Comp2,~Comp3,
        1,1,NA,NA,
        2,NA,1,NA,
        3,NA,NA,1)

df %>% 
  mutate(Comp2 = case_when(
    Comp2 == 1 ~ 2,
    T ~ NA_real_
  )) %>%
  mutate(Comp3 = case_when(
    Comp3 == 1 ~ 3,
    T ~ NA_real_
  )) %>% 
  unite("group",c(Comp1,Comp2,Comp3),remove = F,na.rm = T) %>% 
  mutate(group = str_extract(group,'\\d'))
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Amazing!!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Great! If that's the case, please mark the answer as 'correct'.

Comment: I am new to the platform and I am not allowed to mark answers as usful (,which I don't understand). But I will do as soon as I am allowed to!

Comment: Hey, sorry to ask about this again. I understood the solution and implemented it in the code but it does not work. No transformed column, no added column in the data set but also no error. It should mutate the existing columns right?

Comment: How strange. Yea, mutate overwrites the column already there if you put the same name.  Tip: Try to work in a stepwise fashion. Do each operation and check that you get the results you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that. It is not even changing the 1 to 2 in the Comp2 column. I just don't understand why.

Comment: "MoneyInvested <dbl+lbl>,
#   CompensationGroup <chr>, Compensationproject1 <dbl>, ..." I can see that in the tibble so something is going on but no changes in the data table and Error if I try to work further with the variable "group" (bc non existent)

Comment: I can help you if you edit you'r original post. Including the code you are now trying, which doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a reproducible example I give you an example with toy data using the `pivot_longer` function from the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)    
data <- tibble::tribble(
      ~Category,          ~MeasureA,          ~MeasureB,          ~MeasureC,          ~MeasureD,
              1, 0.0930158825381708, 0.0138786762728455, 0.0659906858706141, 0.0677226540871513,
              2,  0.103201113378404, 0.0149293889876177, 0.0644022070960172, 0.0605524137103402,
              3,   0.12028743617311, 0.0209951412575897, 0.0598004419601402, 0.0584817396677436,
              4, 0.0996307145670469,  0.016288452837476, 0.0624144782432749, 0.0538275028212587
      )

data
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      Category MeasureA MeasureB MeasureC MeasureD
         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
    1        1   0.0930   0.0139   0.0660   0.0677
    2        2   0.103    0.0149   0.0644   0.0606
    3        3   0.120    0.0210   0.0598   0.0585
    4        4   0.0996   0.0163   0.0624   0.0538
```

The following tells R to take columns 2:5 which hold the values, put the values into a column called `Value` and to put the label from the column names into a column called `Measurement` whilst removing the `Measure` label that is prefixed in the Measure columns.

```
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = 2:5, names_to = "Measurement", names_prefix = "Measure", values_to = "Value")

# A tibble: 16 x 3
   Category Measurement  Value
      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
 1        1 A           0.0930
 2        1 B           0.0139
 3        1 C           0.0660
 4        1 D           0.0677
 5        2 A           0.103 
 6        2 B           0.0149
 7        2 C           0.0644
 8        2 D           0.0606
 9        3 A           0.120 
10        3 B           0.0210
11        3 C           0.0598
12        3 D           0.0585
13        4 A           0.0996
14        4 B           0.0163
15        4 C           0.0624
16        4 D           0.0538
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I am going with the other option because I am not quite at a level where I understand all of what you've written. I will include a reproductible example next time!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself:

data[, "CompensationGroup"] <- 1
for(i in seq(2,3,1)){
  data[which(is.na(data[,paste0("Compensationproject",i)]) == F), "CompensationGroup"] <- as.numeric(i)
}